# how to get vid pid from mac system?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to cross check a process with help of VID and PID from MAC system. Can anyone assist me to get these id from objective C in mac system?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PID is process ID

```
NSProcessInfo *processInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
NSString *processName = [processInfo processName];
int processID = [processInfo processIdentifier];
```

which gets process ID of current process I think..Hope this helps you get started..BTW what is VID??? Vendor ID?